# When to use static/non-static variable in JAVA

Tags: java, static-variables

I don't know when to use a static/non-static variable in a program.

```
package slides;

public class Person {
        
    String name;
    int age;
    boolean isStaff;
    
    public Person(String name, int age, boolean isStaff) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.isStaff = isStaff;
        System.out.println(this);
    }
    
    /*
    public static boolean Staf () {
        
        return isStaff;
    }
    */

}
```

I understand the difference between the non-static/static variable but I just don't know when to use each. So in the above code, why the function `Staf` can not be static? (and when it should be static?)

Answer (score 2):

According to the last question, you do not understand the difference. Every non-static method implicitly receives `this` (as an argument). Static methods are not bound to some instances, so you just can not reference non-static fields. Static stuff can reference only static stuff.

`static` could be used:

- For *Singleton* pattern, for example;
- Or if you want to utilize class as simple *namespace*;
- Or just do not like OOP and going to use COP)

Answer (score 1):

The static method `Staf()` is not allowed to return class instance variables because `Staf()` can be invoked without the class `Person` instance being created. Therefore, `Staf()` can only return static variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access non-static (instance) variables unless you do so with a) a reference to an instance (`myPerson.isStaff`, which would violate encapsulation) or b) from within a non-static (instance) method.

As to when you should use `static`, there are many discussions and diatribes on this very website which can easily be found.